# Do anyone know of a conda channel that contain the mosaic package?

Tags: conda, r-mosaic

Some users have asked me to install the mosaic package ([www.mosaic-web.org/mosaic/](http://www.mosaic-web.org/mosaic/)) in our conda setup, but I cannot r-mosaic anywhere. I do find r-mosaiccore and r-mosaicdata but this is not sufficient according to my users. It is on CRAN, but having something prebuilt is always preferable.

Comment: It isn't available yet, but I just put in [a PR to add it to Conda Forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/16616). If it builds without issue, it's usually a 24 hour turnaround.

Comment: Great news indeed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now [available through Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-mosaic), i.e.,

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge r-mosaic
```

In the future, it would be better to submit a **package request** Issue to the Conda Forge [`staged-recipes` repository](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/issues) when there are packages that you would like added.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works as expected and I have now submitted pull request directly to the repo for r-mosaiccalc based on your hints. (Still waiting for it to be accepted.)